# Carbon fork steerer defect?

Tags: fork, carbon, steerer

Any carbon experts out there? I have zero experience with carbon-* anything.

A brand new unused monocoque CF fork arrived from the manufacturer.
Steerer has an imperfection in it. Very difficult to take a good picture of it, but I tried my best:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Is this something to worry about? Should I send it back to the manufacturer? Or is this normal on carbon forks?

Thanks

================================

UPDATE:

The shop that sold me the frameset said that having looked at the images they believe this to be cosmetic. They also added that they will send images onwards to the OEM factory for a formal comment.

Additionally the shop suggested to replace the fork unconditionally if I don't feel comfortable riding it. (kudos to the shop on that point)

I have not pressed for immediate fork replacement (if the damage is purely cosmetic, the replacement may have same or more of these artefacts, what do I know... ?)

OEM requested the fork serial number (I assume to check their unit-test records?) and confirmed via shop to myself that they deem this to be purely cosmetic and safe to ride.

Going to build the bike up now.

Thanks everyone for responses.

Comment: Almost looks like a hole they’ve imperfectly filled with epoxy? I would contact the manufacturer. If they can’t reassure you that it’s safe to use they should send you a replacement.

Comment: Just sent an email to manufacturer. Will post back once they reply.

Comment: Post updated with latest details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like something (piece of resin or something) fell into the mold and the operator didn’t bother removing it. The fibers would be intact, so it should be fine. Refer to the manufacturer’s email response for final confirmation of course though.

Comment: you were right. I have updated my post with the details of my exchange with the bike shop.